# Transpositions and Permutations - Runtime error

Tags: python, function, math, permutation, discrete-mathematics

This is the question I have to answer:

Find a sequence of transpositions of letters that transform the sequence MARINE (letters are numbered 0..5) to the sequence AIRMEN. Transpositions are represented by pairs of integers. For example, the pair (0,1) transforms MARINE to AMRINE. Transpositions are performed from left to right. You should define the sequence by writing something like this (the dots should be replaced by numbers, each pair in parentheses specifies one permutation, and these permutations are performed sequentially, from left to right):

def sequence():

return [(...,...),..., (...,...)]

When I run the program i seem to get a runtime error. I'm unable to find where the error is. It would be very useful, if I could get some help. Thanks! :)

This is my code:

```
def sequence(original, target):

    permutation = []

    chars_original = []
    for char in original:
        chars_original.append(char)
    #print('original: ', chars_original)

    chars_target = []
    for char in target:
        chars_target.append(char)
    #print('target: ', chars_target)


    for i in range(0, len(target)):
        if chars_target[i]== chars_original[i]:
            continue
        else:
            temp_list = []
            temp_list.append(i)
            j = chars_original.index(chars_target[i])
            temp_list.append(j)
            temp = chars_original[i]
            chars_original[i] = chars_original[j]
            chars_original[j] = temp
            a = tuple (temp_list)
            permutation.append(a)
            #print(permutation)
            #print(chars_original)

    return permutation

sequence('MARINE', 'AIRMEN')
```

Comment: Can you specify the issue you are facing. the sequence you are getting looks corrent

Comment: It's a runtime error not a logic error, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
def sequence(original, target):

    # convert to list so the string becomes mutable
    original = list(original) 
    target = list(target)

    seq = []

    for i in range(len(original)):
        if original[i] != target[i]:
            for j in range(i+1, len(original)):
                if original[j] == target[i]:
                    original[i], original[j] = original[j], original[i] # swap if the same
                    seq.append((i, j))
    return seq

sequence('MARINE', 'AIRMEN')
```

Comment: I still get a runtime error but that should be correct.

Comment: Turns out the answer doesn't require a whole program. You just have to enter the permutations. I feel stupid now lmao

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sequence(y,z):
  a=list(y)
  b=list(z)
  d=0
  l=[]
  while(d<len(y)):
    if(a[d]==b[d]):
      d=d+1
    else:
      e=a.index(b[d])
      a[e],a[d]=a[d],b[d]
      l=l+[(d,e)]
  return l
    
print(sequence("MARINE","AIRMEN"))
```